# How to place movie clips of different aspect ratios into moviepy?

Tags: python, linux, video, moviepy

I have mp4 clips of 2400x1080, but i want to composite them into a clip of 1920x1080 by laying them side by side on a stage of 1920x1080. I've done autodetection to rotate them in moviepy, so they present in the correct orientation. But, moviepy seems to stretch the imported clips before applying them onto the stage. I've set the write_videofile to use the ffmpeg_params of "-aspect" "16:9".

How can i make moviepy not stretch the subclips before pasting them into the main stage clip?